# POSTing all incoming params in Grails at once

Tags: javascript, grails

I have below JavaScript function in Grails:

```
function requestPost() {
        var projectNameFilter = $("input[name='project-name-filter']").val();
        var addressFilter = $("input[name='address-filter']").val();

        $.post(
                '${createLink(controller: "listing", action: "transactions")}',
                {
                    projectNameFilter: eval(projectNameFilter),
                    addressFilter: eval(addressFilter),                        
                    listingType: "${params?.listingType}",
                    propertyType: "${params?.propertyType}",
                },
                function (data, status) {
                    $('#dynamic-table').html(data);
                }
        );
    }
```

Please note the two params:

- **listingType: "${params?.listingType}"**
- **propertyType: "${params?.propertyType}"**

I have a number of those params in this method and all of them should be passed into the controller.

Now my question is: Despite of doing such whole process repeatedly how can i pass all those params at once.

Comment: possibly jquery $('form').serialize()  ... something like this $.post( ${createLink(controller: "listing", action: "transactions")}', $('#formName').serialize(),
                function (data, status) {
                    $('#dynamic-table').html(data);
                }

Answer (score 1):

Since your target is to pass all parameters using javascript, the rendered html needs to contain all parameters explicitly. Hence there cannot be a built-in solution (if you don't want to use session and are not willing to use deprecated `remoteFunction` tags). One workaround is to just iterate over all params and insert them. Note that this might be a security issue:

```
$.post('${createLink(controller: "listing", action: "transactions")}',
{
<g:each in="${params}" var="paramKeyValue">
   '${paramKeyValue.key}': '${paramKeyValue.value}',
</g:each>
},...)
```

I would recommend to do something like this:

```
<g:each in="${['listType', 'propertyType']}" var="paramKey">
   '${paramKey}': '${params."${paramKey}"}',
</g:each>
```

You can also do:

```
${params.subMap(['listType', 'propertyType']) as JSON}
```